# Populate the DropDownList in c# with value from a specific table Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't populate the **DropDownList** in c# with value from a specific table Database.

In this example the row value of `testing` in database is NULL.

I have tried this code without success.

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

My code below.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTesting" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Y"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="N"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**CS**

```
    ddlTesting.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

    string sql = String.Format(@"SELECT ");
    sql += String.Format("  Testing ");
    sql += String.Format(" FROM ");
    sql += String.Format("  `tbl_testing` ");
    sql += String.Format("  WHERE Id IN (?); ");

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
       new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Base64ForUrlDecode(Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString()));
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection.Open();

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(ds);  

                ddlTesting.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Testing"].ToString(); 
                ddlTesting.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Testing"].ToString();   
                ddlTesting.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                ddlTesting.DataBind();

                Response.Write(ddlTesting.Items.Count);

                if (ddlTesting.Items.Count > 1)
                {
                    ddlTesting.Items.FindByValue("Testing").Selected = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    ddlTesting.SelectedValue = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }

            ddlTesting.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("[Y/N]", ""));
            ddlTesting.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("[------------------]", "-99"));
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do really? You want bind `ddl` to database table or ?

Comment: some confusion here...it looks like you are explicitly setting 2 values for ddltesting...but ALSO binding it...which is the case?

Comment: And your `select` query seems not true as `param1` parameter is not defined in query.

Comment: you can just databind the dropdownlist directly without all this faffing about manually reading things from datatables. Plenty of examples online. You can also configure it so you can specify a few values manually as well as the databound options, if need be.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 thank you for interest. In my database I have memorized the value of column testing, This value can be Y, N or null. I need selected true this value on my ddlTesting.

Comment: @Aria thank you for interest. In my database I have memorized the value of column testing, This value can be Y, N or null. I need selected true this value on my ddlTesting.

Comment: findbyvalue does a search in the combobox...since your values are y or n...there won't be a value called testing in there.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this :

```
    OleDbConnection conn = 
       new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT 
                                    IFNULL(Testing,'[Y/N]') AS Testing
                                    FROM tbl_Testing
                                    WHERE ID = @param1", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Request.QueryString["sId"].ToString());

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                string result = reader.GetString(0);
                ddlTesting.SelectedValue = result;
                ddlTesting.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with below line:

```
ddlTesting.Items.FindByValue("Testing").Selected = true;
```

Instead of using Column Name `"Testing"` in hard code, you have to use some value existed in the Data Table values.

That way your above code executes with no errors with no changes in databinding.